# How to concatenate inside the _e() function the right way?

Tags: theme-development, translation

I'm trying to create a function for the title inside my functions.php, I'm having a problem with the search title part where I have to concatenate here's the part with issues:

```
elseif (is_search()) {
_e('Search for ', 'textdomain') . '&quot;' . esc_html(the_search_quey()) . '$quot; - '; }
```

this one gives a title like this: Search for searchtermsitename

no quotes and the search term is attached to the site name.

I tried this one:

```
elseif (is_search()) {
_e('Search for ' . '&quot;' . esc_html(the_search_quey()) . '$quot; - ', 'textdomain'); }
```

it doesn't work either, this one outputs: searchtermSearch for "" sitename

it's better than the first one but he search query is before, and can't figure out why.

so any help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`the_search_query()` echoes itself, so by putting it into another echo function (what `_e()` is) you'll get result as in second example.

It isn't recommended to use variables or function inside l18n functions, because they can't be translated, for more information see Otto's: [Internationalization: You’re probably doing it wrong](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/).

So you should use code like this:

```
printf( __( 'Seach for &quot;%s&quot;, 'textdomain' ), get_search_query() );
```

Note that I'm using `get_search_query()`, because it simply returns value instead echoing it, also it passes query sting through `esc_attr()` and no need for `esc_html()`.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: I like it when I go to answer a question and somebody's already quoted me. :)

Comment: @Otto quoting you will be trending this year, WordCamp San Diego showed it. :)

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use `%s` placeholders in combination with the `sprintf` or `printf` function.

```
printf(__('Search for “%s”', 'textdomain'), esc_html(get_search_query());
```

http://php.net/sprintf

Also note that `the_search_query()` *outputs* its result directly, you need `get_search_query()` which *returns* the result.

Comment: it's still giving the same output like my second try

Comment: Updated with `get_search_query()` instead of `the_search_query()`.